# Mapping relationships from multiple databases in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have a multi-database application configured with NHibernate. The entities that correspond to tables from each database are in their own separate assemblies (an assembly per database if you will). I have a need/desire to relate an entity from one database to an entity of another database. Everything up to this point works as I want it to (the application handles multiple session factories, etc.).

The relationship I want is many-to-one, but in reality my application only cares about one side of the relationship (for reasons that aren't relevant). The relevant entities are Project and PMProject, where a Project HAS A PMProject. When I map the many-to-one, I get the following error:

```
NHibernate.MappingException: An association from the table PROJECTS refers to an unmapped class: SDMS.PPRM.PMProject
```

The Project mapping itself reads (ignore the funky column naming; it's an Oracle db):

```
<many-to-one name="PMProject" class="SDMS.PPRM.PMProject" column="PM_PROJECT_ID" cascade="none" />
```

In the class attribute, I'm referencing the appropriate assembly, but I get that error which seems to tell me it simply can't find the mapping file for PMProject.  But that file exists (it's set as embedded resource), the session factory instantiation works without fail; so I'm at a loss on how to tell the Project mapping how/where to look for the appropriate mapping.  Is there something I'm missing? A better way to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the curious - why do you need multiple databases?

Comment: Requirement of the client.  They have an existing database that is used by other applications/services.  Our application has it's own independent database, and certain biz workflows require reading/updating from/to both locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to bypass my "ideal" scenario and avoid having a direct object relationship between entities of the different databases.  For this app, that's ok, for future apps with the same req, I'd like to find a suitable solution.

Comment: Got reasonable solutions? I got the same problem: many-to-one mapping from two classes from different database-connections.

Answer (score 0):

The error makes it clear that the mapping for PMProject was not loaded.

If the mappings reside in a different assembly, you need to add that assembly to the configuration.

Comment: Perhaps not obvious to someone new to NHibernate, but this was certainly something I had to do, even just to get a basic unit test working.